# Prove that $|A\cap B| \le \frac {1}{2} |A|$ where $A,B$ are two subgroups of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group, $A,B$ are subgroups of $G$ and $A$ isn't a subgroup of $B$.

Prove (by using Lagrange's theorem) that $|A\cap B| \le \frac {1}{2} |A|$.

$ $

This is what I have so far:

$|A\cap B| \le |A| $ because $A\cap B$ is a subset of $A$ (by definition).

From the same reason we get :

$|A\cap B| \le |B| $

I also know that $A\cap B $ is a subgroup of $G$ (I already proved it) which implies that $|A\cap B|$ divides $|G| $  .

I'm not sure from where to start and how the fact that $A$ isn't a subgroup of $B$ helps me.

Can you please provide me an hint how to start this proof?

Comment: $A\cap B$ is  also a subgroup of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though $A$ and $B$ are not subgroups of eachother, $A\cap B$ is a subgroup of both. Now use Lagrange's theorem, together with the fact that $|A\cap B| \neq |A|$.

Comment: Actually I already showed it. I should have written it in my question. I know that $|A\cap B|$ divides $|A|$ and $|B|$. I'll try to use the fact $|A\cap B| \ne |A|$.

Comment: I'm getting a weird result : $\frac {|A|}{|A\cap B|} \ge \frac {|A|} {|A|}$ which is 1... What am I missing?

Comment: Since $|A\cap B|$ is a subgroup of $A$, Lagrange's theorem says that it must have an order that divides $|A|$. But since $A$ is not a subgroup of $B$, there must be elements in $A$ that are not in $B$, so we must have $|A\cap B| \lneqq |A|$. The greatest number strictly less than $|A|$ that divides $|A|$ (assuming $|A|$ is even) is $\frac{|A|}{2}$, and there's your result. If $|A|$ is odd, the greatest proper divisor is even smaller.

Comment: I'm feeling so silly that I missed it. I understand it now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just one more question, we know in general that $A\cap B$ is a subgroup of $A$ because $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq G$ is a subgroup of $G$ ? Or should we should it by definition (that is to show there is an identity, inverse and closure) ?

Comment: "Subgroup" just means "subset that is a group (with the inherited operation)". For instance, $A\cap B$ is a subgroup of $G$, so it's a group. It is at the same time a subset of $A$, and therefore a subgroup of $A$.

Comment: Clear and simple. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Since $\;A\cap B\lneqq A\;$ (why?), we get that it must be $\;[A : A\cap B]\ge 2\;$ . Deduce now.

Comment: I missed that $A\cap B$ isn't subgroup a of $A$ . Thanks. Trying to solve it now.

Comment: Actually it seems very logical to me but I just can't find a way to bring it into an equation.

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB Oh, but **it is a subgroup** of $\;A\;$...and also of $\;B\;$!  Waat the above says is that it is a *proper subgroup* of $\;A\;$ . Try to think a little longer and think of what Lagrange's Theorem tells you about index of a subgroup in a finite group.

Comment: Yes.. My mistake. I understood you. I meant that $A\cap B$ is a proper subgroup of $A$.

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB No ! It may be that **none** is a subgroup of the other one. The only thing you know is that $\;A,B\;$ are subgroups of $\;G\;$ *and* $\;A\;$ is **not** a subgroup of $\;B\;$ . You should really take a little more time to read *carefully*, understand and work out this.

Comment: What? But that is exactly what you wrote there...

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB Obviously you're confusing things very badly or else you don't know basic group/set theory notation...and now I see you re-edited your comment and now it is true: Yes, the **intersection** of $\;A,B\;$ is a subgroup of both, **not** $\;B\;$ a subgroup of $\;A\;$ , of course.

Comment: Well, as far as I know what you wrote in your answer means $A\cap B$ is a proper subgroup of $A$. I really can't understand your last comment.

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB It is just that when I answered, your comment said " I mean that B is a proper sbgp. of A". and then you edited it and wrote the correct "...$\;A\cap B\;$ subgroup of $\;A\;$" . Don't waste more time and try to solve your problem now. .

Comment: Oh.. I'm sorry. You were too fast. I'm very sorry I confused you. Thank you very much for your help!